# Calendar Overlays and Split DNS

Tags: calendar, url

I have extended my main sharepoint 2010 webapp to provide extranet access.

I can now access my site from the internal network using http://spoint.domain.internal/ and from the outside using http://spoint.mypublicurl.com/

The problem I have is Calendar overlays - If someone creates an overlay from the internal network side, then the URL is wrong for the external users and vice versa.

So, how can we specify the URL for calendars etc so that it works for both user populations?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah this bug is annoying.

My half baked attempt to solve this, was to have two views, one for intranet and one for extranet, and then set the overlays on each view to be the appropriate url. I suppose you could try to set the aggregation dynamically with a custom list web part?

Or you could add two different calendar overlays to the same view, one for each url. You will get the error message, but you could hide that with javascript. As long as you dont need more than 5 (half 10)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.

You might encounter this issue with other features, not just with overlays. So I'd say solve this with governance: have a policy that design should only be done on the internal access, while contributors can work on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

There is a KB from MS that fixes this issue - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2553031/en-us. From description

Consider the following scenario:

- You configure Alternate Access Mappings (AAM) for a SharePoint Foundation 2010 site collection.
- You create an overlay to an existing calendar.
- You try to access the calendar in the site collection.

In this scenario, you cannot access the calendar.